# I don't understand use of "you" in "away support you were amazing"

Tags: grammaticality, vocative

> Fun game, good performance from the boys and away support you were amazing.

I saw this sentence on Son HeungMin's instagram.

As far as I understand meaning of this sentence

> "good performance" **and** "away support" **were** amazing

Did I understand this sentence correctly? (I didn't consider "you")

I wonder why "you" is needed in this sentence and how it is used.

Comment: You can't really apply grammar rules to a stream of consciousness of texts, chats, and rambling. For one, it's 3 sentences. You were amazing.

Comment: Yes, it jumps from the writer's comments on the game to a direct address to the 'away supporters', without any punctuation.

Comment: Compare "The marching band was great. Tubas, you rule!"

Answer (score 5):

The message uses extremely informal writing. There are three separate parts:

- "Fun game" Hopefully self explanatory.
- "good performance from the boys" This is complimenting "the boys" (the players) on how they played.
- "away support you were amazing." This uses a [vocative](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/vocative_case_commas.htm) ("away support") which would have to be written with a comma in even slightly formal writing:

  > ...away support, you were amazing

  In this case, using a vocative means that there can be a direct address ("you") while still making it clear who's being addressed. The alternative would be to not address them directly ("away support was/were amazing", with singular "was" being used in American English and plural "were" in British English) but this feels noticeably different from the original, since you're not treating the away support as part of the conversation. By the way, "away support" refers to the fans who travel to the team's away games.